# Closing a JFrame using a button in eclipse

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm a rookie when it comes to programming. We have this project about a log-in profile account. I just started doing it; and I came across a specific problem. I want to close a frame using a button.

```
buttonenter.setText("Enter");
     buttonenter.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){
       public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae){

           }
    });
```

I tried placing my frame.dispose();, set.Visible(false) etc.  but i just got an error. I don't quite get. I really appreciate the help! Thank you!

Comment: Look like duplicated question:  
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688874/close-window-on-button-click

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple example of what you're trying to do. What errors are you receiving?

```
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JButton btnClose = new JButton("CLOSE");
    btnClose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnClose, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. :D I got my answer. the setVisible and dispose() was helpful. I guess I should read more. :D Problem solve! :D

Answer (score 3):

from [JButtons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) you can to call

- `JFrame#dispose();` (terminating current JVM)
- `JFrame#setVisible(false);` (hide JFrame)
- `System.exit(0);` (terminating current JVM)

and/or with (another standard ways are)

- [`setDefaultCloseOperation();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29)
- add [`WindowListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) and override proper event [windowClosing();](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosing%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29)

Comment: +1 See also this [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5540802/230513) using `dispatchEvent()`.

Answer (score 0):

when you close any objects by false visible, actually you just hide that object whereas the object stays in the memory yet.

you better use the
 ***frame.dispatchEvent(new windowEvent(frame,windowEvent.window_closeing));*** method